# Dynamic LINQ expression execution on List<ClassName>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of class defined by me. All the required data is filled in a object named `data` and that object is added in the list.

```
List<ClassName> dataList = new List<ClassName>();
dataList.Add(data);
```

I want to compile a Linq expression `exp` on it. All the conditions or filtering logic is dynamically generated in 'exp'. I want to execute this `exp` on `dataList`.

```
var result = dataList.Where(exp.Compile());
```

But I am getting the below error -

> system.collections.generic.list does not contain a
>   definition for where and best extension method overload has some
>   invalid arguments.
>   using System.Linq; is there in the library.

In exp I am having something like this -

```
{p2 => p2.supt.Select((item, index) => 
    new { item, index }).Where(x => x.index > 4)}
```

Comment: I suppose you have `Sytem.Linq` in your list of `using`, don´t you?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Its already added.

Comment: is `Compile` a method on the `IndicatorData` class?

Comment: What's the type of `exp` and how did you create it?

Comment: exp is an object of System.Linq.Expressions .

Comment: Can you show us the code where the exp object is created?

Comment: Try `dataList.AsQueryable().Where(exp);`

Comment: Try dataList.Where(x => x.Compile());

Comment: @ArpitGupta: `Expression` doesn't have a `Compile` method. `LambdaExpression` and `Expression<TDelegate>` do. If `exp` is an `Expression<Func<IndicatorData, bool>>` then this should work, if it's another kind of expression then you'll get the warning you've shown. So what type is `exp` exactly?

Comment: @PieterWitvoet Its in the same way you explained. Sorry for not describing it properly.

Comment: @ArpitGupta why Compile method??

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki Still the same error.

Comment: What type is `exp`? How are you building `exp`?

Comment: Show how `exp` is defined, not what it *should* look like.

Comment: The code you have added doesn't show any type information, so it's still impossible for us to see what exactly you're doing wrong.

Comment: you couldn't use your expression as Where , Where expression should be of the type Expression<Func<IndicatorData, bool>>

Comment: @Jcl Expression<Func<IndicatorData, List<int>>> exp;

Comment: That's the problem then. `Where` predicates must return a `bool`, not a `List<int>`.

Comment: And your expression is something as Expression<Func<IndicatorData, anonymousType>>

Comment: @ArpitGupta `Where` needs a `Func<IndicatorData, bool>`... that's your problem there

Comment: Yes, It seems the problem. I am working on it, and will let you guys know about further progress.